# How to specify Primary sort order using MySQL COALESCE

Tags: mysql, coalesce

I have a legacy table that uses Parent/Child structure with it's ID, and I need to sort it by the **Names** of the Parent, then the Child (Parents have `null` parent_id).

I've been able to get it to sort by the Child name with the SQL shown below, but am unable to get it to do the same for the primary (`Cables` should be before `Cameras`).

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id,a.name
FROM `equipment` AS a
ORDER BY COALESCE(a.parent_id, a.id), a.parent_id IS NOT NULL, a.name
```

I've tinkered with the various ORDER possibilities, but cannot get the sort that I need.  Any guidance is appreciated.

**Table Rows**

```
id  | parent_id | name
--------------------------------
1   | null      | Cameras
2   | 1         | HandyCam 2000 5-50
3   | 1         | Netgear 360
4   | null      | Tripods
5   | 4         | Deluxe Tripod
6   | null      | Lighting
7   | 6         | Light Diffuser
10  | 6         | Really bright bulbs
11  | 1         | 16MM Handheld
12  | 6         | Big Lightbulb assembly
13  | 4         | HandyCam Stand
16  | 4         | My New Tripod
181 | null      | Cables
```

**Sorted Results (with only Children being sorted)**

```
id  | parent_id | name
--------------------------------
1   | null      | Cameras
11  | 1         |    16MM Handheld
2   | 1         |    HandyCam 2000 5-50
3   | 1         |    Netgear 360
4   | null      | Tripods
5   | 4         |    Deluxe Tripod
13  | 4         |    HandyCam Stand
16  | 4         |    My New Tripod
6   | null      | Lighting
10  | 6         |    Really bright bulbs
12  | 6         |    Big Lightbulb assembly
7   | 6         |   Light Diffuser
181 | null      | Cables
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table with itself, so you can get the name of the parent of each child, and use that in the sort instead of `COALESCE(a.parent_id, a.id)`

```
SELECT a.id, a.parent_id,IF(a.parent_id IS NULL, a.name, CONCAT('   ', a.name)) AS name
FROM `studio_tvs_equipment` AS a
JOIN studio_tvs_equipment AS b ON IF(a.parent_id IS NULL, a.id = b.id, b.id = a.parent_id)
ORDER BY IF(a.parent_id IS NULL, a.name, b.name), a.parent_id IS NOT NULL, a.name
```

[DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4d9d3/7)

Comment: Where can I send you money???? Thank you SO much....I figured it was a join, thus the aliasing in the simple SQL....thanks again!